# Sort n-dimensional numpy array by sorting highest dimension and afterwards reordering entire segments

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, numpy-ndarray

I've got a list of ndarrays (all arrays are of the same dimensions but there can be n dimensions) which I need to compare with each other to eliminate duplicates. For that reason I am trying to sort all arrays equally.

A quick eample for 2d and 3d arrays:

```
[[1, 0]  == [[0, 1]   ==  [[1, 0]  ==  [[0, 1]
 [0, 1]]     [0, 1]]       [1, 0]]      [1, 0]]

[[[1,1],[0,2]],[[0,0],[0,0]]] == [[[0, 0], [0, 0]],[[1, 1],[0, 2]]] == [[[0, 0], [0, 0]],[[0, 2], [[1, 1]]] ...
```

I don't care how it is ordered, i just want to find, handle and afterwards eliminate duplicates.

I tried using `numpy.sort(array)` which can sadly miss duplicates (e.g. `[[0,0],[0,1]]` and `[[0,1],[0,0]]`).
If I sort by every dimension starting with the highest it destroys my structure (eg. `[[1, 1], [0, 2]]` becomes `[[0, 1], [1, 2]]`).

From a nested list point of view, I think, the best idea is to first sort all lists at depth n. Afterwards sort the nested lists at depth n-1 ... 0 by first ordering by sum and afterwards if they are equal by comparing the elements.

Comment: Do you consider two arrays to be equal if they have the same items in the same rows irrespective of order? How many dimensions do you have, you only report 2 here.

Comment: The arrays can have n dimensions. I don't expect that more than 6 dimensions will actually be used, but I can't say for sure.
Arrays are considered equal if they can be transformed into each other using symmetry.
Example: 
`[0, 1] == [1, 0]`
`[[0, 1][0, 1]] == [[1, 0][0, 1]] == [[0, 1][1, 0]] == [[1, 0][1, 0]]`
`[[[0, 1][0, 1]][[0, 1][0, 1]]] == [[[0, 1][0, 1]][[0, 1][0, 1]]] == [[[0, 1][0, 1]][[1, 0][0, 1]]] == [[[0, 1][0, 1]][[0, 1][1, 0]]] == [[[1, 0][1, 0]][[0, 1][0, 1]]] ...`

Comment: `[[1,0],[0,1]` and `[[0,1],[0,1]` are not identical by symmetry, since you only "rotate" the first row. Also, you're mentioning sorting but would `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1, 3, 2]` be considered equal?

Comment: Yes, `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1, 3, 2]` are to be considered equal. But they would need to be in the exact same order. So one should be reordered to either `[1, 2, 3]` or `[1, 3, 2]`

Comment: Ana what about `[[1, 1], [0, 0]]`? Would it be equal to the arrays in the first example? And `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` / `[[1, 4], [2, 3]]`?

Comment: No those wouldn't be considered equal. I think its better if I put it this way: All arrays are structured the same made from nested lists each containing 2 elements. If i can swap these 2 elements, be they nested lists or integer values, and it equals another list/array, they are equal.

Comment: I suggest you first sort the arrays by dimension and only comapare those with the same dimension. As a shortcut, ignore those having a different sum. Then you can compare the nested levels if they have the same elements by converting them to sets.

Comment: The arrays are already all of the same dimension. The shortcut is a nice idea, however I don't see how the comparison with sets is supposed to work at dimensions > 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could use a recursive sorter. I'm providing a python solution here since I believe there is no advantage  of using numpy here:

```
def sorter(lst):
    if isinstance(lst, list):
        return sorted(map(sorter, lst))
    else:
        return lst
```

Or, maybe more generic using a try/except (this would also work on numpy arrays):

```
def sorter(lst):
    try:
        return sorted(map(sorter, lst))
    except TypeError:
        return lst
```

Examples:

```
example1 = ([[1, 0], [0, 1]],
            [[0, 1], [0, 1]],
            [[1, 0], [1, 0]],
            [[0, 1], [1, 0]],
            [[0, 0], [1, 1]], # different
           )

example2 = ([[[1,1],[0,2]],[[0,0],[0,0]]],
            [[[0,0],[0,0]],[[1,1],[0,2]]],
            [[[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,2],[1,1]]],
            [[[0,0],[0,0]],[[1,1],[2,0]]],
            [[[0,0],[0,0]],[[1,2],[1,0]]], # different
           )

[sorter(x) for x in example1]

[[[0, 1], [0, 1]],
 [[0, 1], [0, 1]],
 [[0, 1], [0, 1]],
 [[0, 1], [0, 1]],
 [[0, 0], [1, 1]]] # different

[sorter(x) for x in example2]

[[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 2], [1, 1]]],
 [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 2], [1, 1]]],
 [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 2], [1, 1]]],
 [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 2], [1, 1]]],
 [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 1], [1, 2]]]] # different
```

Comment: First of all thank you! It works like it is supposed to. Do you have any ideas on how to improve performance as its a bit slow.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Since you have to sort all branches, the complexity increases for each new dimension.

Comment: Thats why i hoped numpy would provide a solution. I'll mark your answer but am always open for further ideas. Thank you

Comment: I'd also be interested to get a faster approach. I think it might be possible to find a faster solution using lower level coding (i.e. C routines and not python), but I think the overall complexity will remain the same.